# String out of bounds exception

Tags: java

Given a string, return true if the string starts with "hi" and false otherwise. Example output:

```
startHi("hi there") = true
startHi("hi") =true
startHi("hello hi") =false
```

Actual code:

```
   public boolean startHi(String str) {
  String firstTwo = str.substring(0,2);

if (str.length() < 2) return false;

  if (firstTwo.equals("hi")) {
  return true;
  } else {


  return false;
  }
}
```

Everything runs, except strings that are less than 2 characters. It keeps giving error of :

Exception:java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2 (line number:2)

Comment: Is this homework? If not, use the one line `return str.startsWith("hi");`

Comment: i wish everyone to stop downvoting my questions all the time.. it is somethign i do not understand, i apologize it is too basic

Comment: I wish everyone stop giving stacktrace with error line number without indicating us which line correspond to that line number...

Comment: @johnc. Wasn't me who downvoted, however its possible whoever did felt this is a situation that can be solved by using a debugger. Generally, its expected that a user exhaust all possible avenues before posting. Just remember, if you're using something like Eclipse, you can set a breakpoint somewhere and use the inspector to execute code and play around until you find an answer. And as lpratlong indicated, its also helpful to know where in the code the error is occuring; stacktraces are great, but we can't determine which line number is which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the `substring` call **behind** the length check!

```
public boolean startHi(String str) {

  if (str.length() < 2) return false;

  String firstTwo = str.substring(0,2);
  if (firstTwo.equals("hi")) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

The call to `substring` fails otherwise, since it - as the exception tells us - requires a string of length 2 (or longer).

**BUT**

The entire method could be much less complex since Java strings have a `startsWith` method:

```
public boolean startHi(String str) {
  return str.startsWith("hi");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try inverting the first 2 strings of the method.

```
public boolean startHi(String str) {
    if (str.length() < 2) return false;

    String firstTwo = str.substring(0,2);
    ....
}
```

Otherwise, if you leave the `substring` line in first place, you're already supposing that the string is at least 2 characters long. And it will cause an exception if this isn't the case. Putting the length verification in first place guarantees the minimal length of the string.

Beyind that, you can try using the String method `startsWith` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
public boolean startHi(String str) {
  if (str.length() < 2) return false;
    else{
        String firstTwo = str.substring(0,2);
          if (firstTwo.equals("hi")) {
            return true;
           }
              else {
                 return false;
              }
          }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comment as well, consider using the built in startsWith method of String class. Its implementation is available through the sun jdk source code.

```
/**
     * Tests if the substring of this string beginning at the
     * specified index starts with the specified prefix.
     *
     * @param   prefix    the prefix.
     * @param   toffset   where to begin looking in this string.
     * @return  {@code true} if the character sequence represented by the
     *          argument is a prefix of the substring of this object starting
     *          at index {@code toffset}; {@code false} otherwise.
     *          The result is {@code false} if {@code toffset} is
     *          negative or greater than the length of this
     *          {@code String} object; otherwise the result is the same
     *          as the result of the expression
     *          <pre>
     *          this.substring(toffset).startsWith(prefix)
     *          </pre>
     */
    public boolean startsWith(String prefix, int toffset) {
        char ta[] = value;
        int to = toffset;
        char pa[] = prefix.value;
        int po = 0;
        int pc = prefix.value.length;
        // Note: toffset might be near -1>>>1.
        if ((toffset < 0) || (toffset > value.length - pc)) {
            return false;
        }
        while (--pc >= 0) {
            if (ta[to++] != pa[po++]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }



public boolean startsWith(String prefix) {
        return startsWith(prefix, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use startsWith method of Strings, but it is required to check first if its null.

```
public boolean startsWithHi(String str) {
  if (str == null) {
    return false;
  }
  return str.startsWith("hi");
}
```

In case a String starting with "HI" is also required to return true, you should do str.toLowerCase().startsWith("hi");